# Silverlight - how to programmatically select items in a data bound ListBox?

Tags: silverlight, listbox, data-binding

I have a ListBox (AvailableDevicesListBox), which is populated using data-binding in Silverlight 3.  The binding is to a collection of objects of type *DeviceDTO*.  It is set up to allow multiple selections, and this all works fine.

However, I'm trying to get a 'Select All' button working, and if I iterate through the AvailableDevicesListBox.Items collection, I'm returned *DeviceDTO* objects, not ListBoxItem objects, so I have no way of selecting / deselecting the items in the list box that I want.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys - I'd seen that SelectedItems was readonly, without realising I could then use Add().  Works beautifully now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you would need to use [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems(VS.95).aspx) property of the ListBox to add all the items you need to select (I guess all of them if you need to select all). Below is a small example which worked fine for me:

```
// create collection of DeviceDTO objects
List<DeviceDTO> listItems = new List<DeviceDTO>();

listItems.Add(new DeviceDTO("test0"));
listItems.Add(new DeviceDTO("test1"));
listItems.Add(new DeviceDTO("test2"));

// bind listbox to the collection
testListBox.ItemsSource = listItems;

// select all items
foreach (DeviceDTO item in listItems)
    testListBox.SelectedItems.Add(item);
```

hope this helps, regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way I did this:

Xaml

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ListBox x:Name="list" SelectionMode="Multiple" />
    <Button Content="Select All" Width="100" Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

```
var items = new List<string>(){"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
list.ItemsSource = items;
```

}

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in list.ItemsSource)
    {
        list.SelectedItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```